# Condition for being 'injective in each variable separately'

Tags: functions, terminology

Is there an established term for a function on a product set that is not injective but is injective with respect to each argument individually? The motivating example is the canonical projection $\pi: X \times Y \to X$ which, while not injective for $|Y| > 1$, is "injective on $X$" in the sense that

$$ \pi(a,c) \not= \pi(b,d) \implies a \not= b$$
for $a,b \in X$ and $c,d \in Y$.

Specifically, I am seeking to show that functions $y \mapsto (s_1(y),s_2(y))$ and $y \mapsto (t_1(y),t_2(y))$ are equal if $\pi_i(s_1(y),s_2(y)) = \pi_i(t_1(y),t_2(y))$ for $i=1,2$.

Comment: I believe you meant to say $\pi(a, c) \ne \pi(b, c) \Longrightarrow a \ne b$.

Answer (score 0):

To show that functions $y \mapsto (s_1(y),s_2(y))$ and $y \mapsto (t_1(y),t_2(y))$ are equal if $\pi_i(s_1(y),s_2(y)) = \pi_i(t_1(y),t_2(y))$ for $i=1,2$, just note that

$$\pi_1(s_1(y),s_2(y)) = \pi_1(t_1(y),t_2(y))\iff s_1(y)=t_1(y)$$
$$\pi_2(s_1(y),s_2(y)) = \pi_2(t_1(y),t_2(y))\iff s_2(y)=t_2(y)$$